# Customized ClassFileTransformer conflicts with Eclipselink on Glassfish V4

Tags: java, glassfish, eclipselink, bytecode, instrumentation

I am using ClassFileTransformer to transform byte code at class loading time with Glassfish V4 + Eclipselink 2.5.

I configured Glassfish V4 with adding -javaagent:${path}/Lifecycle.jar , which is transforming classes at load time too.

But after apply the -javaagent:${path}/Lifecycle.jar, eclipselink cannot work properly.

Questions:

1. Why this happens? Eclipselink cannot compatible with another ClassFileTransformer?
2. Somebody is saying that with EclipseLink, no javaagent option is needed in glassfish, then does load time weaving happen?
3. How does weaving conflicts with another class file transformer?
4. What options can I have to avoid the conflicts? Can I use the way that does not need to specify javaagent option?

And exceptions are as following:

> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
>   Exception Description: An internal error occurred while accessing method [_persistence_set_incompleteScheduleOrders]

on class [class net.madz.scheduling.entities.ConcreteTruckResource].

Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

Comment: Please show only parts of the stacktrace which are necessary.

Comment: After I changed eclipselink to StaticWeaver at compile time. This error does not occur. But I still want to get more solutions about transform class file at load time without using javaagent or modify startup class main method.